# JQuery Tokenizing Autocomplete w/ trigger key

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Is there a good solution to create textfield inputs like those of Facebook or Google+ status updates and posts where a tokenizing autocomplete is allowed to happen after certain trigger keys like "@" or "+"?

It seems like there are a couple of good tokenizing autocomplete plugins but I'm trying to find a way to call the autocomplete only when the key is present before a term but let's the user type plain non-autocompleted text otherwise.

It seems like you might be able to hack something together with bind but I'm pretty new to JavaScript so if there is a simple more elegant solution I'd love to hear it.

Comment: This isn't exactly a duplicate, but a question and answer that may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089406/autocomplete-in-middle-of-text-like-google-plus/7222592#7222592

Comment: Thanks! I will take another look at that one, might have stuff I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery is not very difficult. First set a class to identify your input boxes. For example:

```
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="the_name" />
```

Then, you can simply capture the keyup event and check for the key you need. For example, @ symbol has the keycode 64

```
$(".autocomplete").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 64) {
        // your event handler
    }
});
```

You can see all event codes and more info about .keypress() [here](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

Your event handler may use the [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function to ask the server for the data to fill your selector.

If you want to autocomplete after entering some text, for example if the user writes "@tyle" you have to modify the condition in the above code, to get the last word written and check if it has an @ at the beginning.