# autocomplete of words in the middle (jQuery UI)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Anyone know good sample code using jQuery UI's autocomplete widget that can autocomplete words in the middle of a text box, not just autocomplete of the word at the end only?

I'm using the jquery UI autocomplete widget for a component that supports entry of multiple tags. It's like like stack overflow's tag editor, but simpler: no fancy formatting in the autocomplete dropdown, no "tag" background images in the edit box.  I started with the [jQuery UI Autocomplete Multiple sample](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple) and modified it.

It's working OK, except autocomplete doesn't work for tags in the middle of a multi-tag string.  For example, if I type `C Fortran` and then put the caret right after `C` and type `+`, I'd expect to see `C++` in the autocomplete list but instead I see `Fortran` again.

Here's the code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/WCfyB/4/

This is the same problem described by [autocomplete in middle of text (like Google Plus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089406/autocomplete-in-middle-of-text-like-google-plus), but the problem in that question was simpler because he could rely on an empty `@` in the text to signal when to show the autocomplete. In my case, I can't just rely on the text-- I actually need to find out where the caret is and autocomplete for the word where the caret is.

I could build this myself using caret or another plugin, but was wondering if there was already a jQuery-UI-based sample online that I could use without re-inventing another wheel, especially if there are browser-specific corner cases to worry about.  Ideally, it'd behave like this: whenever the user places the caret inside or at the end of a tag (where tags are always separated by 1+ spaces), autocomplete is shown for that tag. Know a good sample?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any examples like this, but here's something that you could start with:

```
var availableTags = [ ... ]; 

function split(val) {
    return val.split(/ \s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}

$("#tags")
    .bind("keydown", function(event) {
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB
                                   && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            var results = [],
                selectionStart = this.element[0].selectionStart
                term = extractLast(request.term.substring(0, selectionStart));

            if (term.length > 0) {
                results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(availableTags, term);
            }
            response(results);
        },
        focus: function() {
            return false; // prevent value inserted on focus
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value.substring(0, this.selectionStart));
            terms.pop();  // remove the current input
            terms.push(ui.item.value);        // add the selected item
            this.value =
                $.trim(terms.join(" ") + this.value.substring(this.selectionStart)) + " ";
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/WCfyB/7/

The major caveat here is that the `selectionStart` method does not work in IE. You can replace those function calls with one of those plugins you mentioned in your question.