# Triggered @mention Autocomplete like Facebook, Twitter and Google+

Tags: jquery, facebook, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have been trying to make something like Facebook @tagged Friend name add in text area. I have been using jquery ui auto-complete to do the job , it's working fine except that I want some symbol such as @ or ~ to start the tag, I can't figure it out how. Anyone has ideas ? I'm using it for multiple tag of friends just like Facebook.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [autocomplete in middle of text (like Google Plus)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089406/autocomplete-in-middle-of-text-like-google-plus)

Comment: you can see similar plugins at [here](http://flipnotes.net/notes/note/6/commet-autocomplete-for-username-and-type)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a plugin to accomplish this:

http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9391/

```
$('#inputbox').triggeredAutocomplete({
    hidden: '#hidden_inputbox',
    source: "/search.php",
    trigger: "@" 
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a bootstrap plugin library that I wrote. It works on ContentEditable divs: http://sandglaz.github.com/bootstrap-tagautocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

Here's another one (triggered by a starting character like @) http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/tag-friends-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html

Answer (score 1):

THIS MAY BE USEFUL a sample one., : `http://jsfiddle.net/suneeshtr/6ymLD/1/`
also check :`http://www.hawkee.com/snippet/9391/`

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try something like this ... Hope it works..

```
$q=$_POST['searchword'];
$q=str_replace("@","",$q); 
$q=str_replace(" ","%",$q);
$sql_response=mysql_query("select * from data where fname like '%$q%' or lname like '%$q%'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_response))
{
  $fname=$row['fname'];
  $lname=$row['lname'];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a couple of years late, but I figured I'd add my two cents since it doesn't appear as if anyone has actually answered the question yet ;) .

The `source` option of jQuery UI Autocomplete is used to specify an array containing the items that are to be displayed in the drop-down list once the widget is triggered. It can be defined as such an array, a function that returns such an array, or a URL to a resource which produces such an array.

If the array which ultimately becomes the value of `source` is empty, the widget won't display a drop-down list. So, defining `source` as a function capable of returning a non-empty array **only when** `@` is entered will make the widget behave as you desire.

If you don't want to go through the trouble of defining such a function, have a look at [Mentionator](https://github.com/klawson88/Mentionator), a jQuery plug-in which provides mention creation and management functionality (as well as helpful auxiliary features) that actually builds on top of the functionality of jQuery UI Autocomplete. Its maintained by yours truly :) .