# Append jQuery autocomplete data to textarea content instead of overwriting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, coffeescript, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to make a `@` other people function in my rails app, just like stackoverflow:

[image]

I've almost finished this function, but I encounter problems, the jQuery auto-compelete data replace my textarea content, not append.

[image]

**Coffeescript:**

```
find_at_sign = ->
  if $("#tags").val().split('').pop() == "@"
    id = $("#tags").data("article-id")
    $("#tags").autocomplete
      source:  '/articles/' + id + '/autocomplete.json'
      minLength: 1

$ ->
  $(document).on("input", "#tags",
  -> find_at_sign())
```

**Article Controller:**

```
  def autocomplete
    @articles = Article.find_by(id: params[:article_id])
    @commentor_names = @articles.comments.map(&:name).uniq
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json {
        render json: @commentor_names
      }
    end
  end
```

**form_html.erb:**

```
 <div class="form-group ui-widget">
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= f.text_area :content, rows: 5, placeholder: '说点什么...', 
          class: 'form-control', id: "tags", 'data-article-id': @article.id.to_s %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried to use `append` method, but doesn't work:

```
$("#tags").append(${this).autocomplete
  source:  '/articles/' + id + '/autocomplete.json'
  minLength: 1)
```

Any help is appreciate！

Comment: You must have some more code after minlength:1. Please show us that too.

Comment: @RohitArora no other codes, I show the all.

Comment: Hope this link helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12438359/jquery-autocomplete-continuation-instead-of-replace

Comment: @RohitArora Thanks a lot, I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my half-hearted attempt at this, based on [this example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple). The important bits are as follows:

- Cancel the built-in [`focus`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-focus) event which attempts to overwrite the value inside textbox
- Cancel the built-in [`select`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) event and configure it to append the selected `@name` inside textbox instead of overwriting it
- Provide a custom [`source`](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) function which extracts the last `@name` from the textbox and looks up that name and returns matching names

```js
var namelist = [
  "Adam",
  "Adrian",
  "Andrew",
  "Charles",
  "Daniel",
  "David",
  "Evan",
  "Henry",
  "Ian",
  "Jack",
  "James",
  "John",
  "Joseph",
  "Justin",
  "Kevin",
  "Michael",
  "Parker",
  "Robert",
  "Thomas",
  "William"
];
$(function() {
  $("#message").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      var match = request.term.match(/@(\w*)$/);
      var names = match ? $.ui.autocomplete.filter(namelist, match[1]) : [];
      response(names)
    },
    focus: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.value = this.value.replace(/@(\w*)$/, "@" + ui.item.value)
    }
  })
});
```

```css
@import url("https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.min.css");

body {
  font: smaller sans-serif;
}
textarea {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<p>Enter some text or @name</p>
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a jquery plugin for this: http://yuku-t.com/jquery-textcomplete/

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of two things:

1. You can simply just `replace` the @ sign with the content you want, but this might get you into problems.
2. You can fetch the cursor position and add the content after the cursor, this might need some work.

Here is an example:

```
 function (tid) {

        node=$('#'+tid)[0];

        try{
        //--- Wrap selected text or insert at curser.
        var oldText         = node.value || node.textContent;
        var newText;
        var iTargetStart    = node.selectionStart;
        var iTargetEnd      = node.selectionEnd;

        if (iTargetStart == iTargetEnd)
            newText         = left+right;
        else
            newText         = left + oldText.slice (iTargetStart, iTargetEnd) + right;

        //console.log (newText);
        newText             = oldText.slice (0, iTargetStart) + newText + oldText.slice (iTargetEnd);
        node.value          = newText;
        //-- After using spelling corrector, this gets buggered, hence the multiple sets.
        node.textContent    = newText;
        //-- Have to reset selection, since we repasted the text.
        node.selectionStart = iTargetStart + left.length;
        node.selectionEnd   = iTargetEnd   + left.length;
            node.focus ();
....
```

[see full code](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtonsStatic.user.js)