# getting jQuery ui autocomplete to work with @mentions only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've had a look at a few questions, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222592/2332251

I'm still having trouble reconciling it with the code I have.

At the moment the following works perfectly for searching a username as I start typing.

```
$(function() {
    $("#appendedInputButton").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,  
    source: "searchusers.php" 
        });                
});
```

The function in searchusers.php outputs the usernames from the database.

As I said, I'm having trouble making other @mention solutions work for me. I've tried copying over other solutions and swapping my details in but nothing seems to work.

So...

1. What do I need to do to my current autocomplete script to make it load only
   when I initially type the '@' symbol?
2. I would really like to be able to have multiple @mentions in my posts
3. (optional) when autocomplete suggests usernames and when I select the username from the list I want it to appear in my post with the @symbol still appended to the front of the username e.g. "hello @john, the @ symbol is still attached to your username"

If you need more info, please comment and I will provide more :)

**Edit** I'm just really unsure of the syntax to make it work. For example, using the example answer I posted above, I came up with (but it doesn't work):

```
function split(val) {
return val.split(/@\s*/);
}

function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
}

function getTags(term, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "searchusers.php",
        data: {
            filter: term,
            pagesize: 5
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: callback,
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });    
}

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#appendedInputButton")
// don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
.bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {

        event.preventDefault();
    }
}).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        if (request.term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
            $("#loading").show();
            getTags(extractLast(request.term), function(data) {
                response($.map(data.tags, function(el) {
                    return {
                        value: el.name,
                        count: el.count
                    }
                }));
                $("#loading").hide();                    
            });
        }
    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var terms = split(this.value);
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push(ui.item.value);
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push("");
        this.value = terms.join("");
        return false;
    }
}).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<a>" + item.label + "&nbsp;<span class='count'>(" + item.count + ")</span></a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
});
```

Where do I insert searchusers.php, #appendedInputButton and other specific info? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The link http://stackoverflow.com/a/7222592/2332251 you provided explains it pretty well. What problems do you have with that solution?

Comment: Hey @claustrofob see my edit - I hope that helps explain my problem.

Comment: Hey @Josh Just created a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/AU92X/1/ Is that similar to what you want to achieve? Just let me know what is wrong here. I tried to guess your requirements.

Comment: Hey @claustrofob that works great, except if I type @ and then anything it suggests the same two results, even if I type @z where z does not appear in either results... Also how do I change var data = { tags: [ ... ]}; into my format i.e. make it take data from 'searchusers.php' instead of pre prepared data? Sorry, I hope that helps!

Comment: Thats is just for testing purposes. Just use your own getTags function.

Comment: Hi @claustrofob sorry to be a pain, I think that's where I'm stuck, I don't know what the getTags function should look like. I'm no javascript pro. What's your take on it, knowing that my url is searchusers.php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will form an answer based on my comments.

First of all lets review the list of requirements:

- autocomplete usernames started with `@` symbol
- prepend usernames with `@` symbol
- multiple @mentions in a text
- edit any @mention anywhere in a text

to implement the last requirement we need some magic functions that i found on stackoverflow:

- `getCaretPosition` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2897229/2335291
- `setCaretPosition` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/512542/2335291

Also to detect a username somewhere in the text we need to define some constraints for usernames. I assume that it can have only letters and numbers and test it with `\w+` pattern.

The live demo you can find here http://jsfiddle.net/AU92X/6/ It always returns 2 rows without filtering just to demonstrate the behavior. In the listing below i've put the original `getTags` function from the question as it looks fine for me. Although i have no idea how `searchusers.php` works.

```
function getCaretPosition (elem) {

  // Initialize
  var iCaretPos = 0;

  // IE Support
  if (document.selection) {

    // Set focus on the element
    elem.focus ();

    // To get cursor position, get empty selection range
    var oSel = document.selection.createRange ();

    // Move selection start to 0 position
    oSel.moveStart ('character', -elem.value.length);

    // The caret position is selection length
    iCaretPos = oSel.text.length;
  }
  // Firefox support
  else if (elem.selectionStart || elem.selectionStart == '0')
    iCaretPos = elem.selectionStart;

  // Return results
  return (iCaretPos);
}

function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}

function getTags(term, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "searchusers.php",
        data: {
            filter: term,
            pagesize: 5
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: callback,
        jsonp: "jsonp",
        dataType: "jsonp"
   });    
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#appendedInputButton").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var term = request.term;
            var pos = getCaretPosition(this.element.get(0));
            var substr = term.substring(0, pos);
            var lastIndex = substr.lastIndexOf('@');
            if (lastIndex >= 0){
                var username = substr.substr(lastIndex + 1);
                if (username.length && (/^\w+$/g).test(username)){
                    getTags(username, function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.tags, function(el) {
                            return {
                                value: el.name,
                                count: el.count
                            }
                        }));
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }

            response({}); 
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var pos = getCaretPosition(this);
            var substr = this.value.substring(0, pos);
            var lastIndex = substr.lastIndexOf('@');
            if (lastIndex >= 0){
                var prependStr = this.value.substring(0, lastIndex);
                this.value = prependStr + '@' + ui.item.value + this.value.substr(pos);
                setCaretPosition(this, prependStr.length + ui.item.value.length + 1);
            }    
            return false;
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "&nbsp;<span class='count'>(" + item.count + ")</span></a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks @claustrofob thank you for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot add a comment, so I'm just going to add this as an answer.

I tried the code snippet you've provided and it worked great. The only problem I had was while editing the mention. I decided to edit from the middle of the mention, the autocomplete showed and I selected an item successfully. Only - it didn't delete the rest of the previous mention, only the letters before the cursor's position.

So I added something extra:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    var pos = comments.init.getCaretPosition(this);
    var substr = this.value.substring(0, pos);
    var lastIndex = substr.lastIndexOf('@');

    var afterPosString = this.value.substring(pos, this.value.length);
    var leftovers = afterPosString.indexOf(' ');
    if (leftovers == -1)
        leftovers = afterPosString.length;

    if (lastIndex >= 0){
        var prependStr = this.value.substring(0, lastIndex);
        this.value = prependStr + '@' + ui.item.value + this.value.substr(pos + leftovers);
        comments.init.setCaretPosition(this, prependStr.length + ui.item.value.length + 1);
    }    
    return false;
}
```

I changed the select function a bit to cover the leftovers. Now, it's searching for the next " " occurrence and adds the length of everything before it to the replaced value.

Hope this helps :)