# Multiple jQuery UI mentions autocomplete on the one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am having trouble getting multiple mentions autocomplete to work @mention - similar to FB etc.

I have looked on SO and found some good examples on doing a basic mentions autocomplete and have based mine on one, namely:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17048788/2981412

I am however needing to get it to work across MULTIPLE (....infinite) textareas on the one page rather than just the one (which the above answer does well).

When I add it to more than one (using class selector, rather than ID) the additional ones do not display properly.
See my basic example with dummy data in this fiddle:

**http://jsfiddle.net/yv8mn/3/**

The top most textarea works fine, but the others show an empty drop down autocomplete menu.

Any ideas?

The JS...

```
function getCaretPosition (elem) {

  // Initialize
  var iCaretPos = 0;

  // IE Support
  if (document.selection) {

    // Set focus on the element
    elem.focus ();

    // To get cursor position, get empty selection range
    var oSel = document.selection.createRange ();

    // Move selection start to 0 position
    oSel.moveStart ('character', -elem.value.length);

    // The caret position is selection length
    iCaretPos = oSel.text.length;
  }
  // Firefox support
  else if (elem.selectionStart || elem.selectionStart == '0')
    iCaretPos = elem.selectionStart;

  // Return results
  return (iCaretPos);
}

function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}

function getTags(term, callback) {
    var data = {
        tags: [
            {username: 'john', count: 1}, {username: 'michael', count: 1} 
        ]
    };
            callback(data); 


}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".appendedInputButton").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var term = request.term;
            var pos = getCaretPosition(this.element.get(0));
            var substr = term.substring(0, pos);
            var lastIndex = substr.lastIndexOf('@');
            if (lastIndex >= 0){
                var username = substr.substr(lastIndex + 1);
                if (username.length && (/^\w+$/g).test(username)){
                    getTags(username, function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.tags, function(el) {
                            return {
                                username: el.username,
                                count: el.count
                            }
                        }));
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }

            response({}); 
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {

            var pos = getCaretPosition(this);
            var substr = this.value.substring(0, pos);
            var lastIndex = substr.lastIndexOf('@');
            if (lastIndex >= 0){
                var prependStr = this.value.substring(0, lastIndex);
                this.value = prependStr + '@' + ui.item.username + this.value.substr(pos);
                setCaretPosition(this, prependStr.length + ui.item.username.length + 1);
            }    
            return false;
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.username+" ("+ item.count+")</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown menus are actually not empty, the list items are just very, very thin. Try clicking on one and you'll see that the information is inserted into the textarea.

So it seems everything works alright, except the styling for some reason.

Comment: Agree, I had noticed that too since. but inspecting them in firebug they do "appear" empty.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem.

It firstly involved removing the following part of my code from the question:

```
.data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.username+" ("+ item.count+")</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    }
```

and replacing it with EITHER of these 2 solutions (both fixed it):

```
$.each($( "ui-autocomplete" ), function(index, item) {
            $(item).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.username+" ("+ item.count+")</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
            };
        });
```

**OR**

```
    $.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                    return $("<li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.username+" ("+ item.count+")</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
                };
}
```

Which would then result in the following code (if using the initial solution):

```
    function getCaretPosition (elem) {

  // Initialize
  var iCaretPos = 0;

  // IE Support
  if (document.selection) {

    // Set focus on the element
    elem.focus ();

    // To get cursor position, get empty selection range
    var oSel = document.selection.createRange ();

    // Move selection start to 0 position
    oSel.moveStart ('character', -elem.value.length);

    // The caret position is selection length
    iCaretPos = oSel.text.length;
  }
  // Firefox support
  else if (elem.selectionStart || elem.selectionStart == '0')
    iCaretPos = elem.selectionStart;

  // Return results
  return (iCaretPos);
}

function setCaretPosition(elem, caretPos) {
    if(elem != null) {
        if(elem.createTextRange) {
            var range = elem.createTextRange();
            range.move('character', caretPos);
            range.select();
        }
        else {
            if(elem.selectionStart) {
                elem.focus();
                elem.setSelectionRange(caretPos, caretPos);
            }
            else
                elem.focus();
        }
    }
}

function getTags(term, callback) {
    var data = {
        tags: [
            {username: 'john', count: 1}, {username: 'michael', count: 1} 
        ]
    };
            callback(data); 


}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".appendedInputButton").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            var term = request.term;
            var pos = getCaretPosition(this.element.get(0));
            var substr = term.substring(0, pos);
            var lastIndex = substr.lastIndexOf('@');
            if (lastIndex >= 0){
                var username = substr.substr(lastIndex + 1);
                if (username.length && (/^\w+$/g).test(username)){
                    getTags(username, function(data) {
                        response($.map(data.tags, function(el) {
                            return {
                                username: el.username,
                                count: el.count
                            }
                        }));
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }

            response({}); 
        },
        focus: function() {
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {

            var pos = getCaretPosition(this);
            var substr = this.value.substring(0, pos);
            var lastIndex = substr.lastIndexOf('@');
            if (lastIndex >= 0){
                var prependStr = this.value.substring(0, lastIndex);
                this.value = prependStr + '@' + ui.item.username + this.value.substr(pos);
                setCaretPosition(this, prependStr.length + ui.item.username.length + 1);
            }    
            return false;
        }
    });
$.each($( "ui-autocomplete" ), function(index, item) {
            $(item).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
                return $("<li>")
            .data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.username+" ("+ item.count+")</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
            };
        });
});
```